# New UIViewController is blank?

Tags: ios, xib

I've set up an .xib file called `NextViewController`. I'm attempting to display it with this code:

```
NextLevelController *myNextLevelController = [[NextLevelController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NextLevelController" bundle:nil];            
[self presentModalViewController:myNextLevelController animated:YES];
```

However, it shows up as a blank display. I have labels and buttons with text entered. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you connected the owner's view outlet to the view in the nib?

Comment: most common problem: view not connected (per Paul), also misspelled nib name is common.  if you have something appearing, that's all that comes to mind (if nothing were happening, there are lots of other possibilities)

Comment: Yes, it's connected via an IBOutlet as a ViewController on the nib. I copied and pasted the name to be sure. The view rolls up just as a modal is supposed to, it's just all white.

Answer (score 2):

```
NextLevelController *myNextLevelController = [[NextLevelController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NextViewController" bundle:nil];            
[self presentModalViewController:myNextLevelController animated:YES];
```

You have used wrong xib name in the code. I've fixed it